# stop any touchend events firing if a touchmove occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

If I have a div which listens for a `touchend` event, how do I stop the touchend event firing if the user touches on the div but then scrolls or touchmoves?

At the moment im doing:

```
$('body').on('touchmove', function(){dragging = true}).on('touchend', function(){dragging = false})
```

and then each `touchend` event I have uses:

```
if(dragging == false){ //do stuff}
```

but I don't want to have to add this if statement to every `touchend` event I have (there are a lot of them).

I've also tried:

```
$('body').on('touchmove', function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
    event.stopImmediatePropagation()
    return false;
})
```

but this didn't stop any `touchend` events firing after a scroll  or touchmove.

Comment: I don't think anything you do in `touchmove` can make you prevent `touchend` form firing. A flag based solution is the only possible solution imho.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to simply de-register any `touchend` handlers in the `touchmove` handler:

```
$('body').on('touchmove', function(event) {
    $('body').off('touchend');
    ...
});
```

although you may wish to allow for a small amount of movement - it's unlikely that the touch input will remain *exactly* still.

You would of course also have to *re*-register your `touchend` event handlers each time you get a `touchstart` event, although in any event (no pun intended) it's kind of good practise to defer registering your `touchmove` and `touchend` handlers until you've received a `touchstart` event so that your UI code doesn't process unwanted events, in the same way that you would typically  defer registering a `mousemove` handler until receiving a `mousedown` event.